# Monitor Printers remotely over SNMP in Ubuntu

Tags: printing, monitor, snmp

We have a lot of printers in company and we want to monitor Page Counts, daily report,etc.
we tested a lot of [monitor tools](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemMonitoring) but they did not meet our requirements, and we found [this software](http://www.fitosoft.com/downloads) for windows which is met our requirements, is there is any alternative tools for Ubuntu.